# Rendering command validation errors across a redirect

Tags: grails, error-handling, render, grails-validation, grails-constraints

I cannot render the errors from my command object. It does the job well but my .gsp view does not render the errors I raise.

Here is my controller action:

```
def handleModifyProfile2 = { CreditProviderModificationCommand cpmc -> // bind params to the command object
   if (cpmc.hasErrors()) {
      flash.message = "Error modifying your profile:"
      redirect(action: "modifyProfile", params: [creditProvider : cpmc])
   } ...
```

Here is how I try to render the errors in my .gsp view:

```
<g:hasErrors bean="${creditProvider}">
   <div class="errors">
       <g:renderErrors bean="${creditProvider}" as="list" />
   </div>
</g:hasErrors>
```

How can I get the errors to be displayed in the view?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't send the command across in a redirect using `params`. You have a couple options:

- `render()` in the error condition instead of `redirect()`ing:

  ```
  if(cpmc.hasErrors()) {
      render(view: 'profile', model: [creditProvider: cpmc])
  }
  ```

  This is the most common idiom for what you're doing.
- Store the command in the session to persist it across the redirect:

  ```
  if(cpmc.hasErrors()) {
      session.cpmc = cpmc
      redirect(...)
  }

  // and in your action
  def cpmc = session.cpmc ?: null
  render(view: 'profile', model: [creditProvider: cpmc])
  ```

  This option is somewhat questionable. If not done correctly, you can pollute the session and leave objects hanging around, taking up memory. If done correctly, though, it can be a decent way to implement a post-redirect-get.

Comment: AH ah ! 
You have ended up 3 hours of roaming. 

Thank you very much !

Comment: Thanks, I found your answer helpful too. BTW, I suppose using flash instead of session directly would prevent session-pollution?

Comment: @tim_wonil Yeah, the flash scope should clean up after itself. I haven't looked to see what it's doing behind the scenes, but I'm guessing it's just using the session for storage. It's probably good for something like this.

Comment: Yeah, using the flash scope to display errors is another common idiom. Not necessarily the best idiom, though. See also http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/chain.html to redirect with a model.

Comment: Hah, I just noticed that `chain` uses flash scope.

Answer (score 0):

With Grails 3 (I don't know if this worked earlier) it's possible to use [the flash](http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Controllers/flash.html) for this. According to the documentation, the flash will be "cleared at the end of the next request".

I like to use a pattern like this:

```
def save(MyDomain myDomain) {
    if (myDomain.validate()) {
        myDomain.save()
    } else {
        flash.errors = myDomain.errors
    }
    redirect(action: 'edit', id: myDomain.id)
}

def edit(MyDomain myDomain) {
    if (flash.errors) {
        myDomain.errors = (Errors) flash.errors
    }
    return [myDomain: myDomain]
}
```

I don't like to use `render()` for this kind of error handling, because it makes URLs shown in the browser inconsistent with the shown page. This breaks when users set bookmarks, for example.